# Calculate the conditional expectation, given two i.i.d. Normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X,Y$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$. Then how to calculate the conditional expectation
$$E[X \mid X\leq a, X+Y\leq b]$$
Thanks